# C# TCP server unreliability, dropping outdated buffered messages

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, buffer

My goal is to build a c'è TCP server that must transmit data that should otherwise be transmitted through UDP, that is unfortunately not an option for me.

The server must transmit a constant stream of realtime data, example: a sequence of numbers
`0 1 2 3 4 5 etc...` and the client must display only the last one.
If everything goes well the client will receive every number, but if for some reason  a packet gets lost I want to detect it and not send it again, but send the latest number instead.

So the question is: is it possible to detect TCP packet loss in C# and clear the buffer without flushing?

Thanks for your time! Fabio Iotti

**UPDATE**
Dropping all new packets except the lost one is also fine!

**UPDATE**
Also detecting ack packets whould suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"No."<sup>1</sup>

At the application level [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) can never have "lost" a packet. It will keep retrying (at the TCP/transport level) such that the application only sees a complete and accurate stream - hence TCP being a *"reliable"* protocol.

If too many packets are dropped the stream will *eventually* timeout, but that's about the extent of detecting a failed connection. ("Heartbeats" and throughput monitoring can be used to detect a slow/failing or high-latency connection, but only from a high-level.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Some tools like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) can play with TCP streams at a lower abstraction level, but this is generally not fitting (or viable) for application code and is not exposed in the [.NET] TCP/Stream API.

Comment: Thanks, then I will have to write a native library by my own.

(I will mark your answer as accepted soon if nobody posts something like an interop or any other hackish thing)